# Excel footer with different size

Tags: java, apache-poi

I have the following code:

```java
final Footer footer = getSheet().getFooter();
final StringBuilder strFooterText = new StringBuilder();
strFooterText.append(DETAILS_FOOTER.get(0));
strFooterText.append("\n");

// another line
strFooterText.append(DETAILS_FOOTER.get(1));
strFooterText.append(getDetails());

final String fnt = HeaderFooter.font(DEFAULT_FONT_NAME, "regular")
  + HeaderFooter.fontSize(DEFAULT_DETAILS_FOOTER_FONT_HEIGHT);
footer.setLeft(fnt + strFooterText.toString());
```

That kind of code works fine when I open the resulting `XLSX` with LibreOffice. When I open it with Excel 2016 the used `fnt` won't work. With the repair option this is gone be removed.

Is there a way to change for the footer the font size to have it working with `Excel2016` (and later)?

---

UPDATE

After the responses I figured out that I have next to the left `footer` a right `footer` with data:

```
footer.setRight("Page " + HeaderFooter.page() + " of " + HeaderFooter.numPages());
```

This result into `CDATA` .

From the updates I figured out that the `font-name` is the trouble maker. Without the font-name it works. So the following code works:

```java
final Footer footer = getSheet().getFooter();
final StringBuilder strFooterText = new StringBuilder();
strFooterText.append(DETAILS_FOOTER.get(0));
strFooterText.append("\n");

// another line
strFooterText.append(DETAILS_FOOTER.get(1));
strFooterText.append(getDetails());

//final String fnt = HeaderFooter.font(DEFAULT_FONT_NAME, "regular")
//  + HeaderFooter.fontSize(DEFAULT_DETAILS_FOOTER_FONT_HEIGHT);
footer.setLeft("&8" + strFooterText.toString());
footer.setRight("Page " + HeaderFooter.page() + " of " + HeaderFooter.numPages());
```

Don't know if there is a chance to set the font-name as well.

Comment: Might help: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/excel/concepts/workbooks-and-worksheets/formatting-and-vba-codes-for-headers-and-footers

Comment: When I inspect the xml file it says something like `<![CDATA[&L&"Arial,regular"&8Mytext>` I wonder how does it distinguish where the font-size ends where it starts... But I guess the approach is not really valid... But what is a correct one?

Comment: When I look into an Excel file (written by Excel 365), the font size is written `&amp;8`.

Comment: I'm not aware that I write anything like `CDATA` - at least not from the provided code.

Comment: For me this works without problems. `Excel 2016` opens the generated `*.xlsx` file and has left part of footer properly set. The `XML` in `/xl/worksheets/sheet1.xml` is: `<oddFooter>&L&"Arial,regular"&8The footer text containing multple lines</oddFooter>`. Not clear where your `CDATA` comes from.

Comment: This seems to be a problem with `xmlbeans` which decides to switch from entity encoding (`&amp;`) to `CDATA` wrapping when too much entities are in text value of a `XML` element. That's annoying. I have no idea how to avoid this.

Answer (score 1):

The `CDATA` issue comes from settings in `xmlbeans`.

`Xmlbeans` uses `XmlOptions` while reading and saving `XML`. There are following settings: [XmlOptions.setSaveCDataLengthThreshold](https://xmlbeans.apache.org/docs/4.0.0/reference/org/apache/xmlbeans/XmlOptions.html#setSaveCDataLengthThreshold-int-) and `XmlOptions.setSaveCDataEntityCountThreshold`. The `setSaveCDataLengthThreshold` sets a minimal length of text content containing entities beyond which `CDATA` gets used. The `setSaveCDataEntityCountThreshold` sets a count of entities in text beyond which `CDATA` gets used. The default of `setSaveCDataEntityCountThreshold` is 5. So if text contents contain more than 5 entities, then it will be wrapped into `CDATA`.

So the `CDATA` problem occurs if a header or footer text contains more than 5 `&`, which in `XML` must be `&amp;`. Then `xmlbeans` uses `CDATA` blocks for that text.

To avoid this the only way would be changing the [POIXMLTypeLoader.DEFAULT_XML_OPTIONS](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/5.0/org/apache/poi/ooxml/POIXMLTypeLoader.html#DEFAULT_XML_OPTIONS). There appropriate settings for `setSaveCDataLengthThreshold` and `setSaveCDataEntityCountThreshold` would must be placed. As `Excel` itself never uses `CDATA` blocks, `apache poi` also should not.

But you should more precise tell which version of `Excel` has problems with these `CDATA` blocks. For me the following complete example produces the wanted results in `Excel 2016` as well as in `Excel 365` (all in `Windows`), even if `CDATA` blocks are used in the `XML`.

```
import java.io.FileOutputStream ;

import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.*;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.*;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.*;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HeaderFooter;

public class CreateExcelFooterText {

 static final String DEFAULT_FONT_NAME = "Arial";
 static final short DEFAULT_DETAILS_FOOTER_FONT_HEIGHT = 8;

 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

  StringBuilder strFooterText = new StringBuilder();
  strFooterText.append("The footer text");
  strFooterText.append("\n");
  strFooterText.append("containing ");
  strFooterText.append("multiple lines");

  String fnt = HeaderFooter.font(DEFAULT_FONT_NAME, "regular")
  + HeaderFooter.fontSize(DEFAULT_DETAILS_FOOTER_FONT_HEIGHT);

  Workbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(); String filePath = "./CreateExcelFooterText.xlsx";
  //Workbook workbook = new HSSFWorkbook(); String filePath = "./CreateExcelFooterText.xls";

  Sheet sheet = workbook.createSheet();
  sheet.createRow(0).createCell(0).setCellValue("A1");

  Footer footer = sheet.getFooter();
  footer.setLeft(fnt + strFooterText.toString());  
  footer.setCenter("&\"Times New Roman,bold\"&24&K00FF00Center footer\n&\"Arial,regular\"&8&K000000further Text");
  footer.setRight("Page " + HeaderFooter.page() + " of " + HeaderFooter.numPages());

  FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(filePath);
  workbook.write(out);
  out.close();
  workbook.close();

 }
}
```

So if you run this complete example, which exact version of `Excel` will not properly show the `*.xlsx` file then?

---

So the problem was not the `CDATA` usage but the hit of a `Excel` limit. See: [Excel specifications and limits](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/excel-specifications-and-limits-1672b34d-7043-467e-8e27-269d656771c3):

> Characters in a header or footer:     255

So a header and/or footer must not contain more than 255 characters in sum.

Comment: I played around and around and around and I think its an `Excel 2016` limit. First of all I'm really surprised that the font in `fnt` works without escaped `quotes` as you did it in the `setCenter`.

Comment: I think the main problem is that `oddFooter` can only contain up to 255 (+/-1) chars for `Excel 2016`. You could test it directly with `Excel 2016` in the UI. The amount of chars include the font-name as well as all other footer information. Hmmm... perhaps an exception would be great (???) - althought don't know if this is a good thing. Since `LibreOffice 7.1` could handle it without problems.

Comment: If that's the limit wouldn't it be wise to raise at least a warning? If not am error?

Comment: @LeO: I filed a bug report. https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=65512